# Laravel multistep form leads to Call to a member function update() on null

Tags: laravel

I am receiving the fatal error "Call to a member function update() on null" when attempting to post from a multi-step form in Laravel.

Content of the Routes.php file

```
Route::get('accounts/create/{step}', 'AccountsController@getAccountStep')->where(['step' => '[1-3]']);

Route::post('accounts/create/{step}', AccountsController@postAccountStep')->where(['step' => '[1-3]']);

Route::post('accounts', 'AccountsController@postAccount');

Route::get('accounts', 'AccountsController@getAccount');

Route::resource('/accounts', 'AccountsController');

Route::get('accounts/success', 'AccountsController@accountSuccess');
```

Content of the AccountsController.php file

```
  public function getAccount()
{

    return view('accounts.create-1');
}

public function postAccount(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'account_no' => 'required|account_no'
    ]);

    $account = Account::firstOrCreate(['account_no' => $request->input('account_no')]);

    $request->session()->put('account', $account);

    return redirect()->action('AccountsController@getAccountStep', ['step' => 1]);

}

public function getAccountStep(Request $request, $step)
{
    return view('accounts.create-'.$step, ['account' => $request->session()->get('account')]);
}

protected $lastStep = 3;

public function postAccountStep(Request $request, $step)
{
    switch ($step)
    {
        case 1:
            $rules = ['account_no' => 'required|min:2|max:50'];
            break;
        case 2:
           $rules = ['bill_to' => 'required|min:3'];
            break;
        case 3:
            $rules = ['phone' => 'required|in:Cats,Dogs'];
            break;
        default:
            abort(400, "No rules for this step!");
    }

    $this->validate($request, $rules);

    $request->session()->get('account')
        ->update($request->all())

    ;

    if ($step == $this->lastStep) {
        return redirect()->action('AccountsController@accountSuccess');
    }

    return redirect()->action('AccountsController@getAccountStep', ['step' => $step+1]);
}

public function accountSuccess(Request $request)
{

    echo '<h1>Account Added</h1>';
}
```

create-1.blade.php

```
{!! Form::open() !!}
    <div class="row" id="progress-bar">
        <img src="/images/dsd-admin-icons/progress-bars/new-acct-1.png" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('account_no','Account Number')  !!}
        {!! Form::text('account_no', null, ['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
        {{csrf_field()}}
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('name','Customer Name')  !!}
        {!! Form::text('name', null, ['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('acct_type','Account Type')  !!}
        {!! Form::select('acct_type', ['cfs' => 'CFS', 'trucking' => 'Trucking'], null, ['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
    </div>

    {!! Form::submit('Continue', ['class'=>'btn btn-warning']) !!}

{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that

```
$request->session()->get('account')
```

returns `null`. Therefore

```
 $request->session()->get('account')->update()
```

cannot work.

I would assume that you store the currently active user account with `$request->session()->get('account')`, right? If yes, please double check that sessions are configured correctly. As the `postAccount()` method looks okay for me I would think that the session is not able to store the data.